# Godot Networking help: "RPC 'updateDataPos' is not allowed from: 1. Mode is 0, master is 1."

Tags: networking, godot

I can't solve this error no matter what I try: "RPC 'updateDataPos' is not allowed from: 1. Mode is 0, master is 1."

I have two peers connected, one is server (id 1), the other has unique network id.

Thanks for assistance!

*lobby.gd*

```
...
    get_tree().connect("network_peer_connected", self, "_player_connected")
    get_tree().connect("network_peer_disconnected", self,   "_player_disconnected")
    get_tree().connect("connected_to_server", self, "_connected_ok")
    get_tree().connect("connection_failed", self, "_connected_fail")
    get_tree().connect("server_disconnected", self, "_server_disconnected")
...
    glob.player_info["net_id"] = id
    if not get_tree().is_network_server():
        var multigame = preload("res://scenes//Play.scn").instance()
        var uid = get_tree().get_network_unique_id()
        get_tree().get_root().add_child(multigame)  
    else:
        var multigame2 = preload("res://scenes//Play.scn").instance()
        multigame2.set_name(str(1))
        multigame2.set_network_master(1)
        multigame2.connect("game_finished",self,"_end_game",[],CONNECT_DEFERRED) 
        get_tree().get_root().add_child(multigame2) 
...
```

*Play.gd*

```
...
    if global.multiplayer_game and is_network_master() and global.client_connected and global.player_info["net_id"] != 1 and get_tree().is_network_server():
        get_tree().get_root().rpc_id(global.player_info["net_id"], "updateDataPos", r_pos_x, r_pos_y)
...
remote func updateDataPos(rposx, rposy):
    r_pos_x = rposx
    r_pos_y = rposy
...
```

Comment: Can you include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are doing? It is hard to help you without seeing any code.

Comment: I second @rcorre. From the error code your rp is disabled. Are you missing a keyword on `updateDataPos` maybe? It's hard to tell without more code.

Comment: I added relevant code. Thanks

Comment: @user3553070 Thanks for adding relevant code. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> get_tree().get_root().rpc_id(global.player_info["net_id"], "updateDataPos", r_pos_x, r_pos_y)

This would call the remote procedure `updateDataPos` on the scene tree root node that mirrors `global.player_info["net_id"]`. You'll want to call `rpc_id()` on the node instance of `Play.gd` i.e. the node `Play.gd` is attached to.

Comment: Thank you, however how can I achieve this since i alread have `get_tree().get_root().add_child(multigame)` which means the node instance of `Play.gd` is attached to the root

Comment: If `mulitgame` is the node Play.gd instance you’ll want to call updateDataPos like: `multigame.rpc_id(global.player_info[“net_id”], “updateDataPos”, r_pos_x, r_pos_y)`

Comment: thank you! the error is gone but now the update function doesn't happen, and error is: _RPC cannot find path: 1_. I guess i could add a new question...

Comment: @user3553070 Make sure that the multigame, or whatever node, exists and is in the same spot on the SceneTree on all instances of the game client that receive the rpc. Godot finds the rpc by NodePath. If `/root/multigame` is the path of this client and the next client has the path `/root/multiplayer/game` it won't find the right node.

Comment: Yes adding a new question is a good idea. Also post a minimal issue-reproducing amount of code. Sometimes that alone will help you solve the issue and help others help you.  Remember that the people reading your question don't have the context you have. You should describe the context like the readers don't have a clue.